# Render unicode emoji in colour in ggplot2 geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, ggtext

I have unicode text that includes emoji. I'd like to render them in a ggplot2 graphic with geom_text or geom_label in a way that includes the emoji's colour. I've looked at `emojifont`, `emo` and `ggtext` and none of these seem to allow this. The issue of course is that the colour of the text in `geom_text` is governed by the colour aesthetic. Is there any way I can get colours rendered in my text, either through geom_text or some other workaround?

Reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)

pets <- "I like    "

cat(pets)

ggplot() +
  theme_void() +
  annotate("text", x = 1, y = 1, label = pets, size = 15)
```

The `cat(pets)` works on screen in RStudio, but the graphic drawn with the last line looks like this:

[image]

Alternatively, with `ggtext::geom_richtext()` I get a similar black and white result and this error message:

```
> library(ggtext)
> ggplot() +
+   theme_void() +
+   annotate("richtext", x = 1, y = 1, label = pets, size = 15)
Warning messages:
1: In text_info(label, fontkey, fontfamily, fontface, fontsize, cache) :
  unable to translate '<U+0001F436>RStudioGD142.6791338582677' to native encoding
2: In text_info(label, fontkey, fontfamily, fontface, fontsize, cache) :
  unable to translate '<U+0001F431>RStudioGD142.6791338582677' to native encoding
3: In text_info(label, fontkey, fontfamily, fontface, fontsize, cache) :
  unable to translate '<U+0001F41F>RStudioGD142.6791338582677' to native encoding
4: In text_info(label, fontkey, fontfamily, fontface, fontsize, cache) :
  unable to translate '<U+0001F422>RStudioGD142.6791338582677' to native encoding
5: In do.call(gList, grobs) :
  unable to translate 'I like <U+0001F436> <U+0001F431> <U+0001F41F> <U+0001F422>' to native encoding
```

Answer (score 5):

OK, here's an answer to my own question.

Overall approach: we convert each emoji to a hyperlink to an image of the emoji, and use `ggtext` to render the new version of combination of text and images.

First we need a vector of all emoji so down the track we will be able to recognise them:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
library(rvest)

# test vector
pets <- "I like    "

# the definitive web page with emoji:
unicode <- read_html("https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html")

ut <- unicode %>%
  html_node("table") %>%
  html_table()

# vector of all emoji - purely for recognition purposes
all_emoji <- ut[,3]
```

Then I borrow with virtually no alteration several functions from [this page by Emil Hvitfeldt](https://www.hvitfeldt.me/blog/real-emojis-in-ggplot2/). Emil had a similar challenge to me, but without the problem of the original emoji just being text.

```
emoji_to_link <- function(x) {
  paste0("https://emojipedia.org/emoji/",x) %>%
    xml2::read_html() %>%
    rvest::html_nodes("tr td a") %>%
    .[1] %>%
    rvest::html_attr("href") %>%
    paste0("https://emojipedia.org/", .) %>%
    xml2::read_html() %>%
    rvest::html_node('div[class="vendor-image"] img') %>%
    rvest::html_attr("src")
}

link_to_img <- function(x, size = 24) {
  paste0("<img src='", x, "' width='", size, "'/>")
}
```

Those links take an emoji and convert it into a hyperlink to an image of the emoji as rendered by the Apple Color Emoji font. So far so good, but I need to extract the emoji from my mixed test in the first place. To do this I wrote two more functions

- to convert an individual token (where a token might be an individual emoji) into an emoji or return it as unchanged text; and
- to tokenize a text string, convert any emoji tokens to images, and then paste them all back together again.

Here's those two functions:

```
token_to_rt <- function(x){
  if(x %in% all_emoji){
    y <- link_to_img(emoji_to_link(x))
  } else {
    y <- x
  }
  return(y)
}

string_to_rt <- function(x){
  tokens <- str_split(x, " ", simplify = FALSE)[[1]]
  y <- lapply(tokens,  token_to_rt)
  z <- do.call(paste, y)
  return(z)
}
```

Now we have everything we need. First I convert my `pets` vector into `pets2`, then I can use `ggplot2` and `ggtext` to render it on screen, in glorious colour

```
pets2 <- string_to_rt(pets)

ggplot() +
  theme_void() +
  annotate("richtext", x = 1, y = 1, label = pets2, size = 15)
```

There we are:

[image]

For completeness, here's how the key objects `pets`, `pets2` and `all_emoji` look when just printed in the R console:

```
> pets
[1] "I like \U0001f436 \U0001f431 \U0001f41f \U0001f422"
> pets2
[1] "I like <img src='https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/237/dog-face_1f436.png' width='24'/> <img src='https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/237/cat-face_1f431.png' width='24'/> <img src='https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/237/fish_1f41f.png' width='24'/> <img src='https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/237/turtle_1f422.png' width='24'/>"
> all_emoji[1:10]
 [1] "face-smiling" "Browser"      "\U0001f600"            "\U0001f603"            "\U0001f604"            "\U0001f601"           
 [7] "\U0001f606"            "\U0001f605"            "\U0001f923"            "\U0001f602"
```

Comment: Close readers will note that this workflow depends on there being spaces on either side of the emoji. I imagine some extra work would be needed to harden this for use with real data.